# TeamFoundationWeb feature

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I'm trying to use the command Import-SPWeb but I get the following --

```
Import-SPWeb : Could not find Feature TeamFoundationWeb.
At line:1 char:1
+ Import-SPWeb "[sitename is here]" -Path "\\ ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...CmdletImportWeb:SPCmdletImportWeb) [Import-SPWeb], SPException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletImportWeb
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Before making the export from your source web you should check if **TeamFoundationWeb** feature has been activated.

And in your destination try to run this cmdlet

```
stsadm -o installfeature -name TeamFoundationWeb
```